# .htaccess - how to change path for specific url

Tags: php, .htaccess

For example, i have this path
`www.example.com/prog/content/tickets/showTicket.php?campid=4`

The question is how can i change it to `www.exmaple.com/?ticket=4`
In .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^ticket/([^/\.]+)/?$ /prog/content/tickets/showTicket.php?campid=$1 [L]
```